# Is the slope of a vertical line infinity or undefined?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, slope

By slope I mean derivative. Is something being infinity the same thing as being undefined?

Is the slope of a vertical line negative infinity or positive infinity?

Comment: We would describe it as undefined, because a slope of $-\infty$ would also be vertical.

Comment: We might call it infinite if we treat $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ as the same (a projective space).

Comment: Would we say that the slope of a vertical line approaches negative infinity or positive infinity depending on how you rotate it to make it vertical?

Comment: A vertical line is not a function and it cannot have a derivative. If you describe the function of x with respect to y, then sure the derivative is ${dx\over dy} = 0$.

Comment: I think the right hand derivative and left hand derivative aren't equal so you can't take derivatives of the vertical line?

Comment: can you take the derivative with respect to the equation y=4? Is y=4 a function?

Comment: @cr001 Why should functions be the only things that have derivatives? (Curiosity prompts me to ask this)

Comment: Yes $y=4$ is a function and it is horizontal. However the vertical line $x=4$ is not a function.

Comment: You could call it infinity, but infinity is of course not a number. Anything you can't define a number to is undefined.

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art By definition of derivative.

Comment: The slope must be finite. A vertical line cannot be described via the slope. But it can easily be described with $x=c$

Comment: y=1/x is locally at some limiting cases linear approximately the vertical line x=c. Do derivatives not exist there?

Comment: @Got No.$\text{}$

Comment: how do you prove that y=4 is a function and x=4 is not a function?

Comment: For every $x$-value , we can have at most one $y$-value, otheriwise we only have a relation. The case $x=4$ is an extreme example of such a relation not being a function.

Comment: are you assuming y=axis is the codomain and x-axis is the domain? If we assumed y-axis is the domain and x-axis the the codomain, you'd be wrong? but domain and codomain are arbitrary

Comment: @Got If you want it this way: the derivative is measured as "units codomain per units domain". If the $y$-axis is your domain, then a vertical line has zero slope.

Comment: in formal terms in a relation R defined from $X \rightarrow Y, \forall x \in X, \exists$  at most one y $ \in Y$ and let $ X$  be the x-axis and the $ Y$  be the y-axis,,, and this relation R is a function by definition.

Comment: Yes, I assumed that we have $f(x)=\cdots$ which we can also interprete as $y=\cdots$. Of course, we could define $f(y)=4$ but in the univariate case, we usually map $x$-values to $y$-values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can only compute derivatives of functions $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ (at least in this context here). A vertical line is no such function. So one can consider it as undefined. At least as long as you insist in defining "slope" as derivative.

But infinities are *not* the same as something being undefined. This depends on the context.