# Is $f(x)=\lim_{m\to\infty}m(x-b)$ the same as $x=b$?

Tags: geometry, limits

I was thinking that maybe a linear function with an infinite slope $$f(x)=\lim_{m\to\infty}m(x-b)$$ would be the same as $x=b$. And I saw another question [Is the slope of a vertical line infinity or undefined?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2432218/is-the-slope-of-a-vertical-line-infinity-or-undefined) where they say the slope of a vertical line is undefined, so I'm not sure on this.

Comment: The slope of a vertical line is undefined.  What you've written doesn't really make sense as $f(x)$ never returns an actual value.

Comment: @Randall well, at least we have $f(b) = 0$ ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment (by Randall), the expression
$$
f(x) = \lim_{m\to \infty} m(x-b)
$$
that you wrote doesn't make sense as a real-valued function. Even if we think of $f$ as an extended real-valued function $f:\Bbb R \to [-\infty,\infty]$, we still have
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases} -\infty &; x<b \\
0 &; x=b \\
\infty &; x>b,
\end{cases}
$$
which is probably not what you are looking for.

However, there is a way to make sense of what it means for the sequence of lines $$L_m = \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : y = m(x-b)\}$$
to converge to the line
$$L_{\infty} = \{ (x,y) \in \Bbb R^2 : x=b \}$$
as $m\to\infty$. One way to do that is to use the concept of [Kuratowski convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kuratowski_convergence), which makes precise how a sequence of sets can be said to converge to a limiting set. In this setting, we can rigorously say that the graphs of the functions
$$
f_m(x) = m(x-b)
$$
converge (in Kuratowski's sense) to the line $x=b$ in $\Bbb R^2$ (since $\text{Gr}\, f_m = L_m$). That being said, the limiting object $L_\infty$ does **not** correspond to a graph of any real-valued function on $\Bbb R$, and it can be misleading to think of it as a "line with infinite slope".